# SQL group values from multiple tables

Tags: join, group-by, sum

I have tried  for a long time to group the results of an outer join between two tables but I have had no luck.

Using the code below I can get a correct output of the new business rate for each property but I only want the total of all the business rate values added together.

I have tried combinations of SUM and GROUP BY but neither have worked.

```
SELECT A.SHOPPING_CENTRE, B.YEAR_RENT*0.1 as business_rate
FROM SHOPPING_CENTRES A RIGHT OUTER JOIN AGENT_LANDLORD_PARTNERSHIP B
ON A.SHOPPING_CENTRE= 'New Change London'
```